# Is it normal for district judges first instance decisions to be appealed to circuit judges in other locations?

Tags: england-and-wales, appeal, county-court

A [judgment](http://nearlylegal.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/LB-Hackney-v-Pavey-Judgment-of-HHJ-Luba-QC-21.11.17.pdf) from clerkenwell and Shoreditch county court district judge (swan) was appealed to a circuit (?) judge in central London (Luba).

Isn’t the point of a circuit judge that they are the more senior appellate judges in a given location of the county court? How would it have “skipped” over from C&S to central London?

Comment: Shoreditch isn't exactly a million miles away from central London

Comment: @alexg no, but it’s also sufficiently big and central that I’d think they’d surely have a resident circuit judge of their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Practice Direction 52B](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part52/practice-direction-52b-appeals-in-the-county-courts-and-high-court):

> The venue for an appeal within the County Court will be determined by the [Designated Civil Judge](https://www.judiciary.uk/about-the-judiciary/who-are-the-judiciary/leadership-judges/designated-civil-judges/) and may be different from the appeal centre.

Comment: Some elaboration would be nice, for example, an explanation of who or what the “designated civil judge” is.

Comment: Okay, that answers “who,” but that’s not very interesting or informative compared to what the role is really about